# AngularJS Formly - Correct selector use in hideExpression on nested key model

Tags: angular-formly

I started to work with formly recently, and I feel the nested keys approach (detailed [here](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/issues/154)) is the most correct so I'm trying to use it in my app.

I ran into an issue with the selector used in "hideExpression". In [this example](http://jsbin.com/gucuposagi) I didn't find the correct way to make the "main.retrival.location" input to show when the "main.rental.retrival.flag" checkbox it's on. I tried with "flag", "model.flag", "model.rental.retrival.flag" and "main.rental.retrival.flag" but none of them works. There's any way to use the value on the checkbox?

Also, I may found an issue but I'm not sure. If there are two keys named identical but in different models and the model variable it's empty, the model option it's not taken in count and the two inputs behave as if they were bound. I modified the [Model example](http://output.jsbin.com/fovopamuca) to show the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [the solution](http://jsbin.com/pawaku/edit?html,js,output) specifically: `hideExpression: 'model.retrival.flag'`. I also updated the `model` property of all of your field configuration objects to be the string version. This is useful so you can re-use these fields elsewhere more easily and/or persist them to disk as JSON. Good luck!